# PHP - nested recursive SQL query doesn't retrieve values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

What i'm trying to do is to print a table and in each row print, for each different value in the DB, the value, the number of the rows in the DB with that value and the sum of the values. Sorry this is not well explayned, more easy go straight to the code

```
$query_voucher1="SELECT * FROM voucher WHERE consegnato= 0 AND IDprestazione=0 ORDER BY codice";
$risultato_query_voucher1=@mysql_query($query_voucher1);
echo "<table class='table table-striped' style='margin-top:70px; width: 60%;'>
      <caption>Riassunto Voucher Liberi</caption>
       <tr>
         <th>Codice di controllo</th>
         <th>Quantità (solo liberi)</th>
         <th>Data Emissione</th>
         <th>Valore Pacchetto (solo liberi)</th>
        </tr>";

$prevcodice= NULL;
$curcodice= 10;
while ($row_voucher1=mysql_fetch_row($risultato_query_voucher1)) {
                if ($curcodice!=$prevcodice){
                  $array_temp_query_value=array();
                  if ($modifica==true){
                  $temp_query_value=mysql_query("SELECT valorelordo FROM voucher WHERE codice='$row_voucher1[2]' AND consegnato=0 ");
                  }else{
                    $temp_query_value=mysql_query("SELECT valorelordo FROM voucher WHERE codice='$row_voucher1[2]' AND consegnato=0 AND IDprestazione=0");
                  }
                  while(mysql_fetch_row($temp_query_value)){
                    array_push($array_temp_query_value, $temp_query_value[0]);
                  }
                  echo "<tr>
                          <td>" . $row_voucher1[2] . "</td>
                          <td>" . count($array_temp_query_value) . "</td>
                          <td>" . print_r($array_temp_query_value). "</td>
                        </tr>";
                  $prevcodice=$row_voucher1[2];

                }
              $curcodice=$row_voucher1[2];
              }

              echo "</table>";
```

So let's say i have a DB with the field `codice` and the many values in this fields are repeated. What i wanna do is take print once the value, once the number of rows where `codice` is the same and once the sum of the values where `codice` is the same.

Not good this explaination either so here the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f5LdLvs0/).

The `$array_temp_query_value` returns the correct number of values so i can count them to fill the second field but all the values in the array are empty so i can't sum them. The query looks good so i have really no idea.

Comment: Why not use groupBy in your query instead?

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not use the [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It’s so awful and dangerous that it was removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) explains best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and there are [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) that can be exploited.

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not suppress errors when calling methods with the `@` operator. If something goes wrong you want to know about it and will need to take corrective action, display a useful message for the user, log the problem, or all that and more. It also makes debugging issues like this a whole lot more complicated if you ignore errors that can be alerting you to problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to calculate this value yourself, just use [`count()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/counting-rows.html), `sum()` and `group by`, e.g.

```
select codice, count(*), sum(codice)
from voucher
group by codice
```

This gives you all existing values in your table, the number of rows of each value and the sums.

---

Upfront, don't use `mysql_*` functions, because they are [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) and removed in PHP 7.

With [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php), taken from the online manual of [`mysqli_fetch_row`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php#example-1924), something along these lines (untested)

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn, 'select codice, count(*), sum(codice) from voucher group by codice');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
    echo '<tr><td>' . $row[0] . '</td><td>' . $row[1] . '</td><td>' . $row[2] . '</td></tr>';
}
```

Comment: i can't apply this solution in my code. Could you provide a draft of the working code?